# I want only the second character of every word if the length of the word is less than 2 it should print @

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want only the second character of every word, and if the length of the word is less than 2 it should print @.

```java
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        String a = "I am an engineer";
        String[] ar = a.split(" ");
        for (int i=0;i<=ar.length-1;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<=ar[i].length()-1;j++){
                if (ar[i].length()>=2){
                    System.out.println(ar[i].charAt(1));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("@");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did this but it's printing this:

```
@ m m n n n n n n n n n n
```

I want only one character for one word. The output should be `@ m n n`

Comment: do you know what your second loop is doing? if no, why did you add the second for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of your second loop completely.

```
public static void main(String []args){
    String a = "I am an engineer";
    String[] ar = a.split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<=ar.length-1;i++){
        if(ar[i].length()>=2){
            System.out.println(ar[i].charAt(1));
        }else{
            System.out.println("@");
        }
    }
 }
```